# VSCodeの｢Markdown Preview Enhanced」でGraphviz(DOT)の図をプレビューする方法を知りたい

Tags: vscode, intellij-idea, graphviz, dot

**質問**
　 Doxygenの文書をVSCodeで編集しようとしています。
　VSCodeの｢Markdown Preview Enhanced」でGraphviz(DOT)の図をプレビューするときの方法を知りたいです。

**現象**
　「@dot」「@enddot」で書いていたdigraphの図が、Doxygenでは見えていたのですが、VSCodeの｢Markdown Preview Enhanced」で見えなくなりました。

```
@dot
    digraph xxx {
        J
        K,L->J
    }
@enddot
```

「```puml」でPlantUML の図は見えますし、digraphの記述はDoxygenで意図したとおり図に変換されていますので、プラグインや設定の不足か記法の問題ではないかと考えています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です。

```` ```dot ```` でプレビューできます。※できました。

Doxygenの文書をVSCodeで編集したかったのですが、VSCodeでのプレビュー(※)は `@dot` を ```` ```dot ```` に変えないとダメなようです。
※｢Markdown Preview Enhanced」

【2020/02/13現在】
今は`Doxygen`の文書を`IntelliJ IDEA`で編集しています。記法を変えなくてよいからです。
`plantuml`を使用すると`Doxygen`と`IntelliJ IDEA`で同じ記法が使えます。
`plantuml`では`dot`の図も書けます。
なお、@startumlと@endumlの中で`plantuml`の記述と`dot`の記述は混在できません。

```
@startuml
digraph xxx {
    K,L->J
}
@enduml
```